# How can I rewrite my removeString function with only one argument?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, arguments

I'm working on an exercise in 'Programming with C'.

I have to create a linked-list and then create a function that removes an entry.

I have managed to do this without too many problems. However, the exercise specifically asks that I do this with just one argument. I cannot work out how to do this.

This is the exercise: *"Write a function called `removeEntry()` to remove an entry from a linked list. The sole argument to the procedure should be a pointer to the list. Have the function remove the entry after the one by the argument."*

My code is below, as you can see, I've made it work with two arguments. How can I possibly assign the next value in order to remove the one in the middle without using two? I've reread everything within the book, searched this site and used Google extensively and I still can't work this out.

Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>


struct entry
    {
        int value;
        struct entry *next;
    };


void removeEntry(struct entry *start, struct entry *remove);


int main (void)
{

    //declarations
    struct entry n1, n2, n3;
    struct entry *list_pointer = &n1;


    //creates list values and links
    n1.value = 100;
    n1.next = &n2;

    n2.value = 200;
    n2.next = &n3;

    n3.value = 300;
    n3.next = (struct entry *) 0;

    //prints out all list values
    while(list_pointer != (struct entry *) 0)
    {
        printf("%i\n", list_pointer->value);
        list_pointer = list_pointer->next;
    }

    //resets list_pointer back to start
    list_pointer = &n1;

    //calls function and removes n2 from list by directly linking n1 to n3
    removeEntry(&n1, &n3);

    //print out amended list
    while(list_pointer != (struct entry *) 0)
    {
        printf("%i\n", list_pointer->value);
        list_pointer = list_pointer->next;
    }

    return 0;
}

void removeEntry(struct entry *start, struct entry *remove)
{
    start->next = remove;
}
```

This is my code for exercise 10.3.

The dummy structure is `struct entry *list_pointer = &n1;` which is used to reference the start of the list throughout the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct entry
    {
        int value;
        struct entry *next;
    };

void insertEntry(struct entry *addOn, struct entry *element);

int main (void)
{


    struct entry n1, n2, n3, addOn;
    struct entry *list_pointer = &n1;

    n1.value = 100;
    n1.next = &n2;

    n2.value = 200;
    n2.next = &n3;

    n3.value = 300;
    n3.next = (struct entry *) 0;

    while(list_pointer != (struct entry *) 0)
    {
        printf("%i\n", list_pointer->value);
        list_pointer = list_pointer->next;
    }

    list_pointer = &n1;
    insertEntry(&addOn, &n1);
    list_pointer = &addOn;

    while(list_pointer != (struct entry *) 0)
    {
        printf("%i\n", list_pointer->value);
        list_pointer = list_pointer->next;
    }

    return 0;
}

void insertEntry(struct entry *addOn, struct entry *element)
{

    //element->next = addOn;
    addOn->value = 400;
    addOn->next = element;
    //addOn->next = (struct entry *) 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to solve the problem if the entries were in an array instead of a list? If so, imagine what that solution would look like.

Comment: No, I don't think that'd be what they want me to do after the 'pointers' chapter :)

Comment: The point is to think about a similar you can solve, and look for similarities between that problem and the one you are trying to solve, and generalize the known solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
void removeEntry(entry *start){
    if(start->next != NULL) {
        start->next = start->next->next;
    } 
    //else you can't really remove the next one, probably log or something then
}
```

Comment: You're a god, thank you. Can you please explain the need for the if statement? I see that the program works with just the body.

Comment: Try it with a entry that has a single element only ;) (or try calling it with &n3)

Comment: But a real explanation, if start->next is NULL it can't be converted to a "struct entry" so it doesn't have a "next" field. So if it doesn't have a "next", you will have a nasty memory access doing start->next->next (because start->next is "nothing" and has no following "->next")

Comment: I got a segmentation fault testing this function by removing all 3 elements. I believe the reason is that at some point, list_pointer will be NULL and the start variable in the function will be the NULL pointer and when you test against start->next, you crash.

Comment: What do you mean? If you pass a NULL value yes, it will be a bad memory access, but that is the user fault. You could make an if case to guard against (start == NULL) but I don't usually do that. Maybe it's a bad practice from me

Comment: I agree with you. My comment only applied to his code in the main function had he removed all 3 items. He only tested one case and the point was for his code to be more defensive. But what if you want to remove the last node? start->next of the last node is NULL, so it does not seem possible to remove the last node.

Comment: The exercise asked to remove the element after the one passed as argument, if you wan't to remove the last you have to pass the one before last. In this case it works and next will become NULL.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, since your exercice is basically asking you to always delete the first element, you need only update your list pointer to point to the node following the node to be "removed". Your prototype:

```
void removeEntry(struct entry **start);
```

In main(), call:

```
removeEntry(&list_pointer);
```

Your function passes the address of the list pointer (so it can be updated):

```
void removeEntry(struct entry **list)
{
    if (*list)
        (*list) = (*list)->next;
}
```

I should add that this assumes the list parameter is always a valid pointer.

Comment: Thank you, how does the double* work in this regard?

Comment: It is a pointer to a pointer variable, in other words, the address of the list_pointer variable; this is what enables you to change its value from within the function.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much